# parsing HTML data in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-3.6, get-request

Let's say I have the following website:

```
https://www.atcc.org/Products/All/CRL-2528.aspx#culturemethod
```

When you go on this website, it displays a bunch of information.
In my case, I just want to the temperature from the Culture Culture Conditions section.

when you scroll down the webpage, you will see 
a section called "Culture Conditions"

```
Atmosphere: air, 95%; carbon dioxide (CO2), 5%
Temperature: 37°C
```

using the requests library, I'm able to get to the HTML code of the page. when I save the HTML and search through it for my data it's towards the bottom

in this form

```
                                    Culture Conditions

                                </th>

    <td>



                                            <div><strong>Atmosphere: </strong>air, 95%; carbon dioxide (CO<sub>2</sub>), 5%</div><div><strong>Temperature: </strong>37&deg;C</div>
```

I'm not sure what to do after this. I looked into using BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML but i was not successful.

this is all the code that I have so far.

```
import requests

url='https://www.atcc.org/Products/All/CRL-2528.aspx#culturemethod'

page = requests.get(url)
textPage = str(page.text)

file = open('test2', 'w')
file.write(textPage)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a regular expression that search for the line starting by `<div><strong>Atmosphere:` and take all until the end of the line. Then I removed every unwanted strings from the result. Et Voila!

```
import re
textPage = re.search(r"<div><strong>Atmosphere: .*", textPage).group(0)
wrongString = ['<div>','</div>','<strong>','</strong>','<sub>','</sub>']
for ws in wrongString:
    textPage = re.sub(ws, "", textPage)
file = open('test2', 'w')
file.write(textPage)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.atcc.org/Products/All/CRL-2528.aspx#culturemethod'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

cc = soup.select('#layoutcontent_2_middlecontent_0_productdetailcontent_0_maincontent_2_rptTabContent_rptFields_2_fieldRow_3 td div')

for c in cc:
    print(c.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
Atmosphere: air, 95%; carbon dioxide (CO2), 5%
Temperature: 37°C
```

To just get the temperature:

```
cc = soup.select('#layoutcontent_2_middlecontent_0_productdetailcontent_0_maincontent_2_rptTabContent_rptFields_2_fieldRow_3 td div')[-1]
cc = cc.text.split(':')[-1].strip()
print(cc)
```

Output:

```
37°C
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you may find useful is something like below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.atcc.org/Products/All/CRL-2528.aspx#culturemethod'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.find_all("strong"):
    if "Atmosphere:" in items.text:
        atmos = items.find_parent().text
        temp = items.find_parent().find_next_sibling().text
        print(f'{atmos}\n{temp}')
```

Output:

```
Atmosphere: air, 95%; carbon dioxide (CO2), 5%
Temperature: 37°C
```